# Instruction h is not supported

Tags: programming, ibm-quantum-devices

I'm new at quantum computing and I'm trying to run a script with IBM quantum. I'm using brisbane and getting that error  "Instruction h is not supported". I get the same error for cx gate as well. Are they really not supported or am I missing something?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can see [here](https://quantum.ibm.com/services/resources?system=ibm_brisbane) that Brisbane basis gates are ECR, ID, RZ, SX, X. You have to transpile your circuit before you run on the device; the transpilation will translate your circuit gates to the device basis gates.

Answer (score 0):

Precisely the above answer, Each quantum hardware is different and has a different set of basis gates. Some can't perform `H`, and some can't perform some other gates. So it is natural to break down these gates into a simpler set of instructions that the hardware can implement, and this is how it is done using `qiskit`.

```python
from qiskit import transpile
backend = "ibm_brisbane"

qc_basis = transpile(qc,backend)
qc_basis.draw('mpl',style='iqx',fold=-1)
```

all quantum hardwares are different and they all have different basis gates. Whenever you are running on an actual quantum hardware, make sure to transpile the circuit first using above, or alternatively

```python
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService, Sampler, Estimator, Session, Options

# Loading your IBM Quantum account(s)

service = QiskitRuntimeService(channel="ibm_quantum")
```

then you can select the least busy hardware or the special one you want:

```python
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider, least_busy
#backend = service.least_busy(simulator=False,operational=True,min_num_qubits=5)
backend = "ibm_brisbane"
print(backend)
```

and while executing the code, (if done on sampler)

```python
shots = 1000
#sampler = Sampler(backend=backend, options={"shots":shots})


options = Options(optimization_level=2)
sampler = Sampler(options=options, backend=backend)
```

This `optimization_level` will automatically transpile the circuit and will look for the best qubits to map your circuit to.